# how to save separate log file for each class or activity in android?

Tags: android

My question is about saving log file into sdcard . Suppose I have 3 class file as class1, class2 and class3. Then I want to save log file as `class1.txt`, `class2.txt` and `class3.txt`.

Comment: Why would you want that?  That would make it almost impossible to figure out what was actually happening in the app on a time basis.  You'd be better off with 1 log file and tags on each line for the class.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan... Actually i have big number of class file and i want to save the log for each file with timing

Answer (score 0):

**Better way to maintain logs:**

Add below code to build.gradle file [Module:app]

Logs has to displayed when app in Debug mode not when it is Release Mode to avoid security concerns.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "IS_DEBUG", "false"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "IS_DEBUG", "true"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

        }
    }
```

**Create on Utility class as follows:**

```
public class Logger {
    //Debug Logs
    public static void d(String tag, String msg) {
        if (BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG) {
            Log.e(tag, msg);
        }
    }
    //Warning Logs
    public static void w(String tag, String msg) {
        if (BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG) {
            Log.e(tag, msg);
        }
    }
    //Verbose Logs
    public static void v(String msg) {
        if (BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG) {
            Log.v(Parent.TAG, msg);
        }
    }
    //Error Logs
    public static void e(String tag, String msg, Throwable t) {
        if (BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG) {
            Log.e(tag, msg, t);
        }
    }
}
```

In your respective classes call define TAG as class name

**ex:private String TAG = "AddNavigationDrawerSctivity";**

**Call as follows:**

**Debug Log :**

Logger.d(TAG, "isMenuFeature() :" + mNavigationMenuItemsModel.isIsMenuFeature());

**Error Log:**

Logger.e(TAG, "Failed"+t.getMessage(), t);

You can use TAG name to filter while working on specific screen.

**Use below code snippet in Timer to capture logs for every 5 secs**

```
String command = "C:\Users\vos\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

Please let know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jeelan... I want to save log for application crash, GPS log, application error, application start/stop etc log on separate file for each type of log.

Comment: in you above solution.how i can save log file for each class into sdcard??

Comment: Well u can use adb commands to store at any place for example : C:\Users\vos\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat or else better you use crashlytics/firebase where u will get logs when app is crashed.Let me check how to execute commands pragmatically  .Please vote up if it heps.

Comment: I think using adb logcat command or dumping log will not solve my problem.I already done some experiment with adb logcat commands. I want to save log with in every 5 seconds .My question is :Suppose I have 3 class file as class1, class2 and class3. Then I want to save log file as class1.txt, class2.txt and class3.txt.